# what are the dimensions of audio in matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio

What are the dimensions of audio just like a pictures has dimensions 3. 1 for rows, 1 for columns and  1 for layers.
I have recorded audio in matlab and converted it into an array through `getaudiodata()` it shows me number of rows = 4000 and number of columns =1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio has always been a 1-dimensional signal.  Audio is stored on a computer due to the fact that we **sample** and **quantize** the audio input.  Sampling refers to how often we grab an audio point to be stored in the file and quantizing refers to the resolution of each audio point itself.  This is represented by a number of bits.  Usually, this is either 8 or 16 bits.

However, you could have **separate** audio tracks for different channels.  For example, stereo usually has left and right audio, and are represented as two individual audio tracks, but if you use `audioread` or `getaudiodata`, you'll get two columns.  Each column represents either the left channel or the right channel.  The number of rows tells you **how many samples** the audio signal consists of.

In general, each column represents an individual audio signal, but audio has always been a 1D signal.  The independent dimension is time, while the dependent dimension is the amplitude or the intensity of the wave at a particular point in time.

Comment: I want to encrypt audio file. If I apply a transformation on audio, will column 1 always transorm to column 1 (Supposing we have only 1 column)?

Comment: Consider accepting my answer if I helped and you no longer need help. Good luck!

Comment: Do you know any technique to encrypt audio? I have converted audio into 1D array.

Comment: @user4129542 - That's too broad to answer.  There are a lot of ways to do it.